# Terminal on Mac,Assemble level programming, emu command

Tags: macos, terminal, qemu

I have installed homebrew from the command given by them on their website
And doing an OS tutorial i wanted to create an OS and test it for a project.
After installing home-brew i successfully installed nam and emu
But emu command is not executing due to some reason
Can anyone help?

```
Last login: Wed Mar  9 14:51:42 on ttys000
    Apples-MacBook-Air-2:~ Supreet$ ls
    Desktop         Movies          boot_sect_simple.asm
    Documents       Music           boot_sect_simple.bin
    Downloads       Pictures        sudoku.c
    Library         Public
    Apples-MacBook-Air-2:~ Supreet$ boot_sect_simple.asm
    -bash: boot_sect_simple.asm: command not found
    Apples-MacBook-Air-2:~ Supreet$ vi boot_sect_simple.asm
    Apples-MacBook-Air-2:~ Supreet$ qemu boot_sect_simple.bin
    -bash: qemu: command not found
    Apples-MacBook-Air-2:~ Supreet$
```

Comment: Have you checked `$PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

All the `homebrew` programs get installed into `/usr/local/bin`, so you need to do one of three things.

**Option 1**

Either type the full path every time you want to use something from `homebrew`, e.g.

```
/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-mips boot_sect_simple.bin
```

**Option 2**

Tell OSX once, manually by typing it in each time you start Terminal, that it should look in `/usr/local/bin` whenever it needs to find a program:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

qemu-system-ppc64  this
qemu-system-m68k   that
```

**Option 3**

Tell OSX every time you log in, automatically, to look in `/usr/local/bin` when it needs to find programs. Do this by starting `TextEdit` and editing a file called `.profile` in your HOME directory and adding in the following line at the end.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Once you have done this, log out and log back in again for the new settings to take effect, then type

```
echo $PATH
```

and check that `/usr/local/bin` appears at the start of your PATH.

Option 3 is normally chosen by most folk!

Comment: I did that but still it is giving the same thing :(

Comment: Which did you try? I gave you 3 options.

Comment: $PATH variable gives


-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory 
Is that a problem?
The third one, though!

Comment: @trojanfoe I have no clue you are right,
But i would really appreciate your help, Please?

Comment: I deleted my comment.  Why don't you help yourself and do some reading?

Comment: @trojanfoe 
Thanks, I will :)
I asked because i have a deadline on a project of OS and was following someone's tutorial and got stuck so that's why
Thanks anyway:)